# VS2015RC Pre-release version of Visual Studio Emulator for Android has Expired

Tags: android-emulator, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2015

Using Xamarin Forms, when I attempt to launch the Android app in VS2015RC, I receive the following error:

> The pre-release version of Android Emulator has expired. Please
>   upgrade to a newer version.

I have searched the web and am unable to figure out where to upgrade for the latest version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can update it from Visual Studio > Tools menu > Extensions and Updates > Updates > Visual Studio Gallery.
[image: Extensions and Updates window]

Alternatively, you can download it from the [Visual Studio Extensions Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/99de92db-2098-423f-b814-f8d9b67a8a95).